Apply similar sort of elements across multiple lists (clustering)
I have

dictionary spots that contains number of spots per position per day (e.g. on day 0, position 'a' has 3 spots), and
dictionary names that contains available names per position per day (e.g. on day 0, position 'a' is occupied by John, Claire and Billy)

Sample
import pandas as pd

spots = {
    0: {'a': 3, 'b': 3},
    1: {'a': 3, 'b': 3},
    2: {'a': 1},
    3: {'a': 3, 'b': 3},
    4: {'a': 4, 'b': 3},
    }

names = {
    0: {'a': ['John', 'Claire', 'Billy'], 'b': ['Paul']},
    1: {'a': ['John', 'Billy', 'Claire']},
    2: {'a': ['Billy']},
    3: {'a': ['Claire', 'Billy'], 'b': ['Paul', 'Peter']},
    4: {'a': ['Anna', 'Claire', 'Billy'], 'b': ['Peter']},
    }

I would like to sort names in the lists so that the position is the same whenever possible (e.g. Billy is available on all days and must therefore be put in the first position, unlike Anna who is available on the least amount of days and must be put at the end of names)
Expected outcome
output = {
    0: {'a': ['Billy', 'Claire', 'John'], 'b': ['Paul', '', '']},
    1: {'a': ['Billy', 'Claire', 'John'], 'b': ['', '', '']},
    2: {'a': ['Billy']},
    3: {'a': ['Billy', 'Claire'], 'b': ['Paul', 'Peter', '']},
    4: {'a': ['Billy', 'Claire', 'Anna', ''], 'b': ['Peter', '', '']},
    }

Own solution
def name_per_category(names):
    unique_names = {'a': set(), 'b': set()}
    for key in names:
        for category in names[key]:
            unique_names[category].update(names[key][category])
    return {category: sorted(unique_names[category]) for category in unique_names}


def sort_names(spots, names):
    output = {}
    sorted_names = name_per_category(names)

    for key in spots:
        output[key] = {}
        for category in spots[key]:
            sorted_list = [''] * spots[key][category]

            if key in names and category in names[key]:
                for name in names[key][category]:
                    # Find the index for each name
                    index = sorted_names[category].index(name)
                    print(index, name)
                    sorted_list[index-1] = name
            output[key][category] = sorted_list
    
    return output

output = sort_names(spots, names)

Wrong output
{0: {'a': ['Billy', 'Claire', 'John'], 'b': ['', '', 'Paul']},
 1: {'a': ['Billy', 'Claire', 'John'], 'b': ['', '', '']},
 2: {'a': ['Billy']},
 3: {'a': ['Billy', 'Claire', ''], 'b': ['Peter', '', 'Paul']},
 4: {'a': ['Billy', 'Claire', '', 'Anna'], 'b': ['Peter', '', '']}}

Other than wrong outcome, my logic seems quite heavy. Is there better way to reason about this type of problem?

Hi! Awesome problem. I upvoted and followed. Personally I would have asked at https://or.stackexchange.com instead, where someone is more likely to say "this sounds like a classical problem I know"

This is most likely solvable with integer linear programming, although writing the constraints and objective as linear is not obvious.

Okay I got a formulation as integer linear programming. Let me write a detailed answer.

@Stef I am able to solve this with CP-SAT but it seems kind of overkill.

This problem can be formulated as integer linear programming.

Call I the set of workers, indexed as i in the formulation. I = {John, Claire, Billy, Paul, Peter, Anne}).
Call J the set of spots, indexed as j in the formulation. J = {0.a.0, 0.a.2, 0.a.3, 0.b.1, ..., 4.b.0}, |J| = 26).
Set J is partitioned horizontally into positions, indexed as P in the formulation. P takes values in {0.a, 0.b, 1.a, ..., 4.b}.
Set J is partitioned vertically into columns, indexed as C in the formulation. C takes values in {a.0, a.1, a.2, a.3, b.0, b.1, b.2}.

Then define binary decision variables X_(i,j) and Y_(i,C):

X_(i,j) = 1 if worker i assigned to spot j, 0 otherwise.
Y_(i,C) = 1 if worker i assigned to at least one spot in column C, 0 otherwise.

Call M a positive integer constant bigger than or equal to the maximum number of elements in a column. For instance you can set M = number of days. M will be used for a big-M constraint.
This gives us the following integer linear program:
OBJECTIVE
    MINIMIZE sum_i sum_C Y_(i,C)                       // for each worker i, minimize the number of columns in which i works at least once

CONSTRAINTS
    forall position P:
        if i in names[P]: sum_(j in P) X_(i,j) == 1    // worker i must be assigned once to position P
        else:             sum_(j in P) X_(i,j) == 0    // worker i is not available for position P
    forall worker i, forall column C:
        Y_(i,C) * M >= sum_(j in C) X_(i,j)            // Y_(i,C) is 1 iff worker i works at least once in column C

DECISION VARIABLES
    forall i, forall j: X_(i,j) in {0,1}
    forall i, forall C: Y_(i,C) in {0,1}

Implementation in python with pulp:
spots_dict = {
    0: {'a': 3, 'b': 3},
    1: {'a': 3, 'b': 3},
    2: {'a': 1},
    3: {'a': 3, 'b': 3},
    4: {'a': 4, 'b': 3},
}

names_dict = {
    0: {'a': ['John', 'Claire', 'Billy'], 'b': ['Paul']},
    1: {'a': ['John', 'Billy', 'Claire']},
    2: {'a': ['Billy']},
    3: {'a': ['Claire', 'Billy'], 'b': ['Paul', 'Peter']},
    4: {'a': ['Anna', 'Claire', 'Billy'], 'b': ['Peter']},
}

# LISTS AND DICTS OF NAMES OF WORKERS, SPOTS, POSITIONS AND COLUMNS

worker_names = sorted(set().union(*(position_v for day_v in names_dict.values() for position_v in day_v.values())))
# workers = ['Anna', 'Billy', 'Claire', 'John', 'Paul', 'Peter']

spot_names = sorted(
    '.'.join((str(day_k), position_k, str(spot_k)))
    for day_k,day_v in spots_dict.items()
    for position_k,position_v in day_v.items()
    for spot_k in range(position_v)
)
# spot_names = ['0.a.0', '0.a.1', '0.a.2', '0.b.0', '0.b.1', '0.b.2', '1.a.0', '1.a.1', '1.a.2', '1.b.0', '1.b.1', '1.b.2', '2.a.0', '3.a.0', '3.a.1', '3.a.2', '3.b.0', '3.b.1', '3.b.2', '4.a.0', '4.a.1', '4.a.2', '4.a.3', '4.b.0', '4.b.1', '4.b.2']

position_names = sorted(
    '.'.join((str(day_k), position_k))
    for day_k,day_v in spots_dict.items()
    for position_k in day_v.keys()
)
# positions = ['0.a', '0.b', '1.a', '1.b', '2.a', '3.a', '3.b', '4.a', '4.b']

all_position_keys = sorted(set().union(*(day_v.keys() for day_v in spots_dict.values())))
# all_position_keys = ['a', 'b']
max_spots = {
    k: max(day_v.get(k,0) for day_v in spots_dict.values())
    for k in all_position_keys
}
# max_spots = { 'a': 4, 'b': 3 }

column_names = sorted('.'.join((position_k, str(spot_k))) for position_k in all_position_keys for spot_k in range(max_spots[position_k]))
# column_names = ['a.0', 'a.1', 'a.2', 'a.3', 'b.0', 'b.1', 'b.2']

spots_in_column = {}
for j in spot_names:
    column = j.split('.',maxsplit=1)[1]
    spots_in_column.setdefault(column, []).append(j)
# spots_in_column = {'a.0': ['0.a.0', '1.a.0', '2.a.0', '3.a.0', '4.a.0'], 'a.1': ['0.a.1', '1.a.1', '3.a.1', '4.a.1'], 'a.2': ['0.a.2', '1.a.2', '3.a.2', '4.a.2'], 'b.0': ['0.b.0', '1.b.0', '3.b.0', '4.b.0'], 'b.1': ['0.b.1', '1.b.1', '3.b.1', '4.b.1'], 'b.2': ['0.b.2', '1.b.2', '3.b.2', '4.b.2'], 'a.3': ['4.a.3']}


from pulp import LpMinimize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable

model = LpProblem(name="repeated-assignment", sense=LpMinimize)

# VARIABLES

X = LpVariable.dicts('X', (worker_names, spot_names), lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Integer')
Y = LpVariable.dicts('Y', (worker_names, column_names), lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Integer')

# OBJECTIVE

model += lpSum(Y[i][c] for i in worker_names for c in column_names)

# CONSTANT

M = len(spots_dict) # = number of days = upper bound on the height of a column

# CONSTRAINTS

for i in worker_names:
    for p in position_names:
        day_k, position_k = p.split('.')
        day_k = int(day_k)
        n_times_assigned_expr = lpSum(X[i][f'{p}.{spot_k}'] for spot_k in range(spots_dict[day_k].get(position_k,0)))
        n_times_assigned_target = int(i in names_dict[day_k].get(position_k,[]))
        constraint_name = f'Worker {i} assigned {n_times_assigned_target} time to position {p}'
        model += (n_times_assigned_expr == n_times_assigned_target, constraint_name)

for i in worker_names:
    for c in column_names:
        constraint_name = f'Y[{i},{c}] is 1 iff {i} is assigned at least once in column {c}'
        model += (Y[i][c] * M >= lpSum(X[i][j] for j in spots_in_column[c]), constraint_name)

print(model)

# SOLVE

status = model.solve()

# DISPLAY RESULTS

print('Assignments:')
for var in model.variables():
    if var.value() == 1:
        print(var.name, end=', ')
print()

Output:
[...]

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                6.00000000

[...]

Assignments:
X_Anna_4.a.3, X_Billy_0.a.0, X_Billy_1.a.0, X_Billy_2.a.0, X_Billy_3.a.0, X_Billy_4.a.0, X_Claire_0.a.2, X_Claire_1.a.2, X_Claire_3.a.2, X_Claire_4.a.2, X_John_0.a.0, X_John_1.a.0, X_Paul_0.b.0, X_Paul_3.b.0, X_Peter_3.b.0, X_Peter_4.b.0,
Y_Anna_a.3, Y_Billy_a.0, Y_Claire_a.2, Y_John_a.0, Y_Paul_b.0, Y_Peter_b.0, 


Processing the solution :-)

@aeiou I just implemented it with python pulp and got a solution with objective value 6 (which means each worker got assigned to only 1 column, since there are 6 workers), here is the list of variables equal to 1: X_Anna_4.a.3, X_Billy_0.a.0, X_Billy_1.a.0, X_Billy_2.a.0, X_Billy_3.a.0, X_Billy_4.a.0, X_Claire_0.a.2, X_Claire_1.a.2, X_Claire_3.a.2, X_Claire_4.a.2, X_John_0.a.0, X_John_1.a.0, X_Paul_0.b.0, X_Paul_3.b.0, X_Peter_3.b.0, X_Peter_4.b.0, Y_Anna_a.3, Y_Billy_a.0, Y_Claire_a.2, Y_John_a.0, Y_Paul_b.0, Y_Peter_b.0,
